# Is using JQuery in MVC project okay?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a Single Page Application in MVC, and found JQuery and Ajax might be good to transport my data between view and controller, and update my GUI. But is this bad practice, and if so, is there a better way?

I know about KnockOut, but it feels a little overwhelming at this point.

Comment: This will be closed as too 'personal opinion' for StackOverflow, but the resounding consensus is Yes! jQuery is your friend. There are alternatives, but jQuery has the largest support in asp.net mvc applications

Comment: But I will just be missing out on Razor script then, if I use JQuery to update my GUI. Isn't that a problem in an MVC project?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused on what you're trying to accomplish then. There's no reason you can't use both Razor and jQuery

Comment: But if I use JQuery with Ajax to call my controller from the view, I don't see how I can use Razor to show the result.

Comment: `$.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")' });` and `public ActionResult MyAction() { return View(); // this uses razor }`. The jQuery/js would then need to parse or display that result (ex: paste it into a div element).

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine; in fact, in many cases that's the preferred way these days, as it would allow you to make your app more responsive and eliminate annoying delays caused by page reloads and extensive communication between the browser and the server.